# Left justification of nomenclature description in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tex

I'm using a LaTeX template (provided by ASME) to write a conference paper.
The *asme2e.cls* class defines a "nomenclature" environment as follows:

```
% Nomenclature environment
\newbox\tempbox
\newenvironment{nomenclature}{%
   \newcommand\entry[2]{%
       \setbox\tempbox\hbox{##1.\quad}
       \hangindent\wd\tempbox\noindent{##1}\quad\ignorespaces##2\par}
       \section*{NOMENCLATURE}}{\par\addvspace{12pt}}
```

which is used, in the *.tex* source file, as follows:

```
\begin{nomenclature}
% [...]
    \entry{$C_{visc}$}{Viscous friction coefficient.}
    \entry{$M$}{Spool mass.}
% [...]
\end{nomenclature}
```

resulting in the description texts not being left justified (since a fixed horizontal space is inserted between the symbol (e.g.: *M*) and the description (e.g.: *Spool mass.*), but the symbols have different lengths (e.g.: *Cvisc* is longer than *M*).

Is there a way to fix the class to have left-justified descriptions?
(I did a few experiments with *\dimexpr* and the *calc* package, but just got a bunch of errors).

(I also asked ASME if they could provide an updated template, but I'm still waiting for their feedback...)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem, but I found a "quick and dirty" workaround, using the *Tabbing* and *setspace* packages.
Here is the new *.tex* source:

```
%[...]

\usepackage{Tabbing}
\usepackage{setspace}

%[...]

\begin{nomenclature}
{\setstretch{1.1}
\begin{tabbing}
\noindent
% [...]
    \entry{$C_{visc}$}\quad\quad\={Viscous friction coefficient.}\\
    \entry{$M$}\>{Spool mass.}\\
    \entry{$v$}\>{Spool velocity.}\\
% [...]
\end{tabbing}
}    % end \setstretch
\end{nomenclature}

%[...]
```

(Clearly, I'm completely bypassing the *\entry* command defined by the *asme2e.cls* class for the *nomenclature* environment).

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to edit the asme2ej.cls file but nothing working for me. Then I ended up using the tabbing and set space packages. However, I did not use the \setstretch, and my document compiled just fine.

```
%[...]
\usepackage{Tabbing}
\usepackage{setspace}
%[...]
\begin{nomenclature}
\begin{tabbing}
\noindent
    \entry{XYZ}\quad\quad\={This is an example}\\
    \entry{PQR}\>{This is an example}\\
    \entry{ZXC}\>{This is an example}\\
    \entry{CVN}\>{This is an example}\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{nomenclature}
%[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when submitting a paper to an ASME journal. My solution was to edit the asme2e.cls file:

```
\newenvironment{nomenclature}{%
\newcommand\entry[2]{\noindent\hbox to 0.05\textwidth{##1}\ignorespaces##2\par}
\section*{Nomenclature}}{\par\addvspace{12pt}}
```

You can change the amount of indentation by changing "0.05\textwidth".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newlength{\nomenlabelindent}
\setlength{\nomenlabelindent}{4em}
\newenvironment{nomenclature}{%
\newcommand\entry[2]{%
   \hangindent\nomenlabelindent\noindent\makebox[\nomenlabelindent][l]{##1\quad}\ignorespaces##2\par}%
   \section*{NOMENCLATURE}}{\par\addvspace{12pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{nomenclature}
    \entry{$A$}  {Parameter} 
    \entry{$B$}  {Parameter} 
    \entry{$C$}{Parameter}
    \entry{$D$}{Parameter}
    \entry{$E$}{Parameter}
\end{nomenclature}

\end{document}
```

**Output**:

[Nomenclature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV3i1.jpg)